# Rotation around an axis from centre of a sphere to a given point

Tags: rotations

I would like to rotate an array of data around an arbitary axis that passes from the centre of a sphere though a given point on its surface.

I have no issue rotation around the x,y,z axes - if we consider a point on a sphere at the  spherical coordinate $(r,\theta,\phi)=(1.0,\pi/2,0)$, convert it to cartesian coordinates via

$x^\prime=r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

$y^\prime=r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

$z^\prime=r\cos(\theta)$

and rotate it by around the y-axis by $\psi=40^\circ$ using (in radians)

$x^\prime=x\cos(\psi) + z\sin(\psi)$

$y^\prime=y$

$z^\prime=-x\sin(\psi) + z\cos(\psi)$

I would then like to rotate the data around the axis that connects the sphere centre and the rotated point.

Many thanks

Comment: Read up on rigid transformations https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation

Comment: Just turn the new axes to one of the "ordinary" axes  rotate, and then turn back.